# How to list all files that are not referenced by symlinks

Tags: linux, unix, find, symlink, uniq

I want to list all files in a directory that are not referenced by any symlink in the same directory. So if a file is referenced by a symlink in another directory that doesn't matter and will still be listed. I tried it with `find`,  `readlink` and  `uniq` but it doesn't do what I want

```
\(
find -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec readlink {} ';' ;
find -maxdepth 1 -type f 
\) > "output"
uniq -u "output"
```

I'm new to Unix/Linux. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Create a temp file containing the names of all the symlinks
tmp=$(mktemp)
find -maxdepth 1 -type l > $tmp

# List all the regular files, and remove (grep -vF) the symlinks
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -vF -f $tmp

# Clean up
rm -f $tmp
```

The `-v` option of `grep` causes it to invert its matching logic. In other words, "give me all the items that **don't** match the pattern." The `-F` option tells `grep` that the pattern consists of a list of fixed strings, as opposed to a regex. You don't want `grep` trying to interpret any special characters in the filenames as regex symbols. Finally, the `-f` option to `grep` tells it to read this list of fixed strings from a file instead of from the command line.